# Is it possible to shrink mdf file in replication server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, shrink

Is it possible to shrink the data file of a SQL Server replication target server and continue the replication operation?

Ideally I'm trying to avoid shrinking the data file to reduce down time, then swap the roles if shrinking is possible.

There is 60% free space in the database after a bulk clean up, so shrinking is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server transactional replication, data is replicated at the table level, not the database itself. So you can make whatever changes you want to the database. The question is why you want to shrink the database in the first place. Check out ShouldIShrinkMyDatabase.com, and make sure you click through to the linked article. – [AMtwo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/52344/amtwo) May 21 '20 at 11:20